# grep not the begining of a line

Tags: regex, grep

I want to find all lines in a file containing a number, but not at the beginning of a line. I tried the following:

```
grep -E '[^^][1-9]?[0-9]+' test.txt
```

However, it does not work: this expression matches the lines starting with numbers consisting of two-(or more) digits. As I understand it, [^^] does not mean "any symbol except the beginning of a line". Why is so, and how to write this correctly?

Comment: Replace `[^^]` with `^[^0-9].*`

Comment: `^` has different meaning inside and outside of character class.. at start of regex, it means an anchor to match start of line, as first character inside character class it means negate the character set specified.. so `[^^]` means any character other than `^`

Comment: Or perhaps it would be better to replace `[^^]` with `^[^0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** according to comment:

This Regex should do it, it matches lines not starting with a number (one or more characters), then find one or more numbers.

```
^[^1-9]+?\d+
```

You will need to set the `'multiline'` option, if you check multiple lines at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the `[^^]` part of your regex. That is a negative character class (a `^` inside the `[ ]` negates what is inside the brackets).

Instead, I think you are looking for `^` outside of the brackets to state 'start of the line' and then a negated character class of `[^0-9]` for something other than a digit at the start of the line:

```
$ echo "1 line
line 2
3 line
line 4
no num" | grep '^[^0-9]'
line 2
line 4
no num
```

Then add `.*` for 'anything of any length' and `[0-9]` for at least one digit to filter for lines that have a digit in the line:

```
$ echo "1 line
line 2
3 line
line 4
no num" | grep '^[^0-9].*[0-9]'
line 2
line 4
```

Or, if you want to be locale aware, you can use POSIX character classes to the same result:

```
$ echo "1 line
line 2
3 line
line 4
no num" | grep '^[^[:digit:]].*[[:digit:]]'
line 2
line 4
```